# displaying fields of selected taxonomy term

Tags: 7, entities, ajax, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to create a minimalistic ordering system. No need for a full fledged solution like Commerce or UC in this case.

Orders are represented as nodes (or maybe as custom entities using ECK, have yet to decide). Products are organized into a taxonomy tree. Hierarchy_select module gives the user a super convenient way of selecting the product.

But there is a problem. I need to display some fields of a product term selected by user. Is there a way to tackle it without writing much of custom code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need this functions:

- [taxonomy_term_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7)
- [taxonomy_term_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_view/7)
- [drupal_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7)

load term by `taxonomy_term_load`, pass it to `taxonomy_term_view` then render it by `drupal_render`

Comment: also you can render individual field using `field_view_field` or `field_view_value`

Comment: Wow, sounds easy. Do I correctly understand it's a part of AHAH handler?

Comment: what are you meaning by "Part of AHAH handler"?

Comment: A callback on a server returning HTML on asynchronous request from a client.

Comment: I know what AHAH is, but what you mean by "Part of ...", no its not part of AHAH handler but can use in it

Comment: Yeah, sorry for confusion. I implemented your idea. Works like a charm :)